# Symfony API-Platform Assert\Choice does not work on setter

Tags: graphql, symfony4, api-platform.com

My app has a very standard user comment feature with also standard possibility for any visitor to mark comments as inappropriate.

In the resolution process for these marked comments the admin will decide which action to take, between no action, edit the comment or remove it.

The CommentReport entity includes Assert\Choice to allow only the 3 choices above.

The issue is that it is accepting any string.

On the Comment entity the set up is as follows:

```
....

 *      graphql={
 *          "withCustomArgsMutation"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
 *              "mutation"=CommentReputationTypeResolver::class,
 *              "args"={
 *                  "id"={"type"="ID!"},
 *                  "resolutionType"={"type"="String!"},
 *              },
 *              "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"put-resolution"}},
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}}
 *          }, 
 .....

 /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=CommentReport::class, mappedBy="comment")
  * @Groups({"get", "get-admin", "get-owner", "put-resolution"})
  */
 private $commentReports;
```

Then the CommentReports entity:

```
 class CommentReport
{
 const RESOLUTION_TYPES = [
    'no_action',
    'edit',
    'remove',
 ];
 .....

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message="commentReport.resolutionType.notBlank",
 *      groups={"put-resolution"}
 * )
 * @Assert\Choice(
 *      choices=CommentReport::RESOLUTION_TYPES,
 *      message="commentReport.resolutionType.choice",
 *      groups={"put-resolution"}
 * )
 * @Groups({"get-admin", "put-resolution"})
*/
private $resolutionType;
```

Then on the DeserializeStage the request is intercepted to handle the setting of each individual CommentReport made for that Comment:

/Stage/DeserializeStage.php

```
        if ($this->isAdmin($user) && $resourceClass === 'App\Entity\Comment' && $operationName === 'withCustomArgsMutation') {
        // get all comment reports
        $commentReports = $deserializeObject->getCommentReports();
        foreach($commentReports as $report) {
            $report->setResolutionType($context['args']['input']['resolutionType']);
        }
    }
```

All of this works but I can input any string and it will be accepted.
Of course, the expected result would be that Symfony would throw an exception for any string not on the RESOLUTION_TYPES array.

For info, this is the front-end mutation that triggers input:

```
 `mutation putCommentReport(
    $commentId: ID!
    $resolutionType: String!
    ) {
    withCustomArgsMutationComment(input: {
        id: $commentId
        resolutionType: $resolutionType
    }){
        comment{
            id
        }
    }
}`;
```

Comment: Looks like the `put-resolution` validation group is not used and should be [annotated appropriately](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation/#using-validation-groups). Serialization groups (configured under `normalization_context` and `denormalization_context`) are unrelated to validation groups.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. In addition to the `validation_groups` annotation, the `Valid()` assertion needs to be added to the relation.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeroen van der Laan pointed out, the validation group annotation was missing on the operation, which should be as follows;

App\Entity\Comment

```
  *      graphql={
  *          "withCustomArgsMutation"={
  *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
  *              "mutation"=CommentReputationTypeResolver::class,
  *              "args"={
  *                  "id"={"type"="ID!"},
  *                  "resolutionType"={"type"="String!"},
  *              },
  *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}},
  *              "validation_groups"={"put-resolution"}
  *          },
```

Additionally, the Valid() assertion needs to be added to the CommentReport relation on Comment:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=CommentReport::class, mappedBy="comment")
 * @Assert\Valid() 
 * @Groups({"get", "get-admin", "get-owner"})
 */
private $commentReports;
```